# Calculate $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{z \sec z}{(1-e^z)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{z \sec z}{(1-e^z)^2}$

Note: $z\in\mathbb{C}$

I tried solve using L’Hopital but not work, moreover i tried using the fact $\sin(z)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$ and nothing. I think this limit going to infinity but i don’t know how prove this.

Answer (score 2):

Since $0$ is a zero of order $1$ of $z\sec z$ and a zero of order $2$ of $(1-e^z)^2$, $0$ is a simple pole of $\frac{z\sec z}{(1-e^z)^2}$ and therefore$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z\sec z}{(1-e^z)^2}=\infty$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jose, can you provide me the theorem that justify this? Thanks!

Comment: Justify what? That if a function $f$ has a pole at $z_0$, then $\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=\infty$?

Comment: No, the argumento that implies 0 is a ponle

Comment: Since the numerator is of the form $a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots$ with $a_1\neq0$ and the denominator is of the form $b_2z^2+b_3z^3+\cdots$ with $b_2\neq0$, you have$$\lim_{z\to0}z\frac{z\sec z}{(1-e^z)^2}=\lim_{z\to0}z\frac{a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots}{b_2z^2+b_3z^3+\cdots}=\frac{a_1}{b_2}\neq0.$$Therefore, $\frac{z\sec z}{(1-e^z)^2}$ has a pole of order $1$ at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

*Without complex analysis.*

Compose the Taylor series (they are simple)
$$ \frac{z \sec z}{(1-e^z)^2}=\frac{1}{z}-1+\frac{11 }{12}z+O\left(z^2\right)$$